# S3 site subdomain hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, subdomain

I have my site ([www.mycompany.com.ar](http://www.mycompany.com.ar)) hosted on my data center. We develop an static site and put it on [www.mycompany.com.ar/myapp](http://www.mycompany.com.ar/myapp). In my country connectivity issues are an everyday thing, so we decided to host a cloud version in AWS S3 and keep both versions working. The domain is handled by our internet provider, how can I map the S3 bucket to a subdomain?

Comment: Try https://m-thirumal.github.io/aws-s3-website-host.html

Comment: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: My main domain is not registered in Route 53, is with registered with our internet provider, a subdomain is what I want to to link to an S3 bucket.